# Use strtok() to break string into 3 parts

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strtok

The following lines of code give me a segmentation fault.  The registers are: inputPtr = 00 PRNT 02 (the correct input from stdin) after fgets, inputPtr = 00 after first strtok(), and inputPtr = (null) after second strtok()

The if/else with the return 3; is an error check.

The problem as I understand it is the second call to strtok() isn't reading in PRNT, so I get why the segfault happens.  I'd just really like to be able to read in PRNT.
A little help would be great!  Thanks!

```
  fgets(input, 15, stdin);
    /*Tokenize instr00 into "00"(instructionCounter) "INST"(operationCode) and "OP"(operand)*/
    if(atoi(strtok(inputPtr, " ")) >= 0 && atoi(strtok(inputPtr, " ")) <= 99)
    {
        *instructionCounter = atoi(strtok(inputPtr, " "));
    }
    else
    {
        return 3;
    }
    inputPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

Comment: is it  `fgets(input, 15, stdin);` or  `fgets(inputPtr, 15, stdin);`

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is meant to be used differently than the way you are using. Here's some documentation from [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok):

> On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. ***In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer*** and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   // fgets(input, 15, stdin);

   char input[20]; // = "00 PRNT 02";
   char* firstToken = NULL;
   char* secondToken = NULL;
   char* thirdToken = NULL;
   int instructionCounter = 0;

   strcpy(input, "00 PRNT 02");
   firstToken = strtok(input, " ");
   secondToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
   thirdToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
   instructionCounter = atoi(firstToken);

   fprintf(stdout, "First token: %s\n", firstToken);
   fprintf(stdout, "Second token: %s\n", secondToken);
   fprintf(stdout, "Third token: %s\n", thirdToken);
   fprintf(stdout, "Instruction Counter: %d\n", instructionCounter);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets do following tests.

```
fgets(inputPtr, 15, stdin);
```

Now `inputPtr` has value `"00 PRNT 02"`  Now using strtok to fetch "00"

```
char *p = strtok(inputStr," ");
```

Now `printf("%s",p)` gives `"00"` as output.

> Does strtok allocates new memory for "00" and returns address to p?
>   Answer is **NO**. It only returns pointer to the first character and shift its internal pointer to beginning of next token. So next time when `strtok(NULL," ")` is called, it begins from that internal pointer.

So `p` points to first character of `inputPtr`. But `printf` prints string till it encounters null character `'\0'`. So `"00"` is followed by null character in `p`. But since `p` points to `inputStr`, so same happens in `inputStr` also.

Therefore the case is that after first `strtok`, the system replaces initial `" "` (space) after `"00"` with null character.

You can check this using following sequence of commands.

```
char *p = strtok(inputStr," ");
printf("%s",p); //output is "00"
printf("%s",inputStr); // output is "00"
```

So when you do `p = strtok(inputStr," ");` the second time, you are tokenizing string `"00"` only, not `"00 PRNT 02"`, hence you are not getting `PRNT` printed. Don't call it again. Imporved code is as follows.

```
fgets(inputPtr, 15, stdin);

int a = atoi(strtok(inputPtr, " "));
if(a >= 0 && a <= 99)
{
     *instructionCounter = a;
}
else
{
    return 3;
}
inputPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
```